# How can I label my current git branch as ok then continue

Tags: git, branch, label, version

I am in the middle of work on a branch.

I've reached a "works so far" point.

I want to clearly label my current state with a label, e.g. "ok_so_far".

So that when I continue and if (... ok when) I mess up I can get back to this point easily.

I know I can refer to the SHA but I was wondering how can I put a label at the current point (kinda like a release label I guess) so that it's really clear what point to go back to and hopefully be referencing a human readable label as opposed to a SHA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for a [*tag*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

```
git tag ok_so_far
```

You can then use the name `ok_so_far` in place of the SHA1 commit identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is a [*note*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html).